# ColdFusion recaptcha form and server validation

Tags: coldfusion, recaptcha

I'm basically wanting to do server side validation and then post the form data to a URL. My Google Foo is lacking as I haven't found any actual examples of doing this.

Here's what I have so far but maybe I'm going about it wrong.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var noRobot = function(response){
            document.getElementById("sub").disabled = false;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Form Post -->
    <CFIF CGI.Request_method IS "post">
        <!-- Sends the recaptcha token to Google to verify -->
        <cfinvoke component="/components/recaptcha" method="isRecaptchaGood" returnvariable="isGood">
        <!-- Only post data if valid recapthca -->
        <CFIF isGood>
            <p>Good Recaptcha</p>
            <!--- 
                How do I foward on all the form data to the API?  
                // <cfhttpparam type="CGI" value="cgivar " name="mycgi">
                // <cfhttp method="Post" url="http://myapi.com/api/users">
            --->
            <CFEXIT>
        <CFELSE>
            <p>Bad Recaptcha</p>
        </CFIF>
    </CFIF>
    <CFOUTPUT>
        <!---
            I used to just post the data to the API, but now I first need to validate the recaptcha response on the server
            <form action="http://myapi.com/api/users" method="post">
        --->
        <form action="#CGI.Script_Name#" method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name = "user" />
        <CFIF Application.recaptcha.enabled>
            <!--- A simple wrapper around generating the recaptcha div with the appropriate key --->
            <cfinvoke component="/components/recaptcha" method="makeRecaptcha">
        </CFIF>
        <button type="submit" id="sub" name="con" disabled="disabled">Continue</button>
        </form>
    </CFOUTPUT>
</body>
</html>
```

As a disclaimer, I have about 6 hours of ColdFusion experience so I assume I'm missing something simple.

Form values edit:

```
<body>
    <cfparam name="form.user" type="string" default="">
    <cfparam name="form.amount" type="string" default="">
    <form action="#CGI.Script_Name#" method="post">
        User: <input type="text" name="user" value="#form.user#" />
        Amount: <input type="number" name="amount" value="#form.amount#" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: What actually happens when you run this code?

Comment: I complete the recaptcha, submit the form and it goes into the `<CFIF isGood>` as expected. But then I need to re-post all the form values `form.user` in this case to an API. There's obviously more than just the one form value in the real application.

Comment: It looks like you have identified the appropriate tags.  You have them in the wrong order, and they are commented out, but you certainly appear to be on the right track.  To transfer form values to http parameters, just put `value="#form.user#"` in your cfhttpparam tag.

Comment: You are headed in the right direction.  Use CFHTTP and add a nested `cfhttpparam` tag for each of the values you want to post. ie `<cfhttp ...><cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="expectedName" value="#form.user#">...</cfhttp>`. In CF, any POST variables exist in a system structure named `FORM`, which can be accessed with either dot notation (`form.someField`) or structure notation (`form["someField"]`).

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but you may also want to check out cfscript. The syntax is more similar to c#. As of CF11, anything that can be done in cfml (ie tags) can be done with cfscript as well. https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/extending-coldfusion-pages-with-cfml-scripting/what-is-supported-in-cfscript.html

Comment: Okay, awesome! It sucks having to re-declare each form field though. If one of you post's your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept as it's solved my problem. I guess I'll just have to accept the first one who creates an answer, sorry :(

Comment: Well, `FORM` is a collection. If the field names are the same those in the API, technically you could cfloop through it and do everything dynamically. However, like anything dynamic it has pros and cons.

Comment: @DanBracuk - You want to write up an answer?

Comment: Not really.  Writing a good one is too much like work.

Comment: Haha, you two are awesome! I was able to get everything working as expected and used a `<cfloop` as suggested. From what I can Google, it seems common practice to declare params for the form fields to ensure they get repopulated in the event the recaptcha is invalid and you redisplay the same form. I added a small snippet above. It works so unless I hear otherwise I'll go with that pattern. Either way, thanks for all the help.

Comment: Heh.. I do not have time to write up an answer right now either. @MisterIsaak - Looks like you benefit from our laziness ;-).  Feel free to post your final code as an "answer" (That is allowed on S.O.).  See also the tip about html injection [mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42421592/104223).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the help from @dan-bracuk and @Leigh, here's the working end result which might help someone else down the road:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--- The callback function recaptcha calls when the user has completed the step--->
    <!--- Enable the Submit button--->
    var recaptchaResponse = function(response){
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--- Declare default values for the form so if it fails validation the form can be redisplayed --->
    <cfparam name="form.user" type="string" default="">
    <cfparam name="form.amount" type="string" default="">
    <!--- On Form Post --->
    <CFIF CGI.Request_method IS "post">
        <!--- Sends the recaptcha token to Google to verify --->
        <cfinvoke component="components/recaptcha" method="isRecaptchaGood" returnvariable="isValid">
        <!--- Only post data if valid recapthca --->
        <CFIF isValid>
            <p>Good Recaptcha</p>
            <!--- Post the to API --->
             <cfhttp method="Post" url="http://localhost:1249/api/users">
                <!--- Send Form field values except for the recaptcha response --->
                <cfloop list="#Form.FieldNames#" item="i"> 
                    <CFIF form[i] eq "G-RECAPTCHA-RESPONSE">
                        <cfcontinue />
                    <CFELSE>
                        <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="#i#" value="#form[i]#">
                    </CFIF>
                </cfloop>
             </cfhttp>
             <cflocation url="next.cfm">
            <CFEXIT>
        <CFELSE>
            <!--- Recaptcha verification failed, redisplay the Form --->
            <p>Bad Recaptcha</p>
        </CFIF>
    </CFIF>
    <CFOUTPUT>
        <!--- Post the Form back to itself first for server side validation --->
        <form action="#CGI.Script_Name#" method="post">
            User: <input type="text" name="user" value="#form.user#" />
            Amount: <input type="number" name="amount" value="#form.amount#" />
            <CFIF Application.recaptcha.enabled>
                <!--- A simple wrapper around generating the recaptcha div with the appropriate key --->
                <cfinvoke component="components/recaptcha" method="makeRecaptcha">
            </CFIF>
            <!--- Initially disable the continue button until the user completes the Recaptcha --->
            <button type="submit" id="submit" disabled="disabled">Continue</button>
        </form>
    </CFOUTPUT>
</body>
</html>
```