# Keeping the values of form on page

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I want to keep the values chosen by the user on the form once they submit the form.

This is what I tried:

```
<cfset tx_name = "">
<cfset id_age1 = "">

<cfif isDefined("form.tx_name")>
    <cfset tx_name = form.tx_name>

    <cfif isDefined("a1")>
        <cfset id_age1 = form.a1>
    </cfif>
</cfif>

<cfoutput>

<input type="text" name="tx_name" value="#tx_name#">

<select name="id_age1">
    <cfloop from="1" to="20" index="a1">
        <option value="#a1#">#a1#</option>
    </cfloop>
</select>

</cfoutput>
```

I am getting the expected result for `tx_name`, however, the `id_age1` is not displaying the correct result. It just resets back to `1`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of that code unnecessary. To define default values for variables that do not exist (different than being empty), simply use [cfparam](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfparam.html). Be sure to specify the variable scope to avoid unexpected results due to scope conflicts:

```
    <cfparam name="form.tx_name" default="">
    <cfparam name="form.id_age1" default="">
```

To pre-select an item within the `<select>` list, you must [apply the `selected` attribute to the appropriate `<option>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2):

```
<select name="id_age1">
   <cfloop ...> 
      <option value="#a1#" <cfif a1 eq form.id_age1>selected</cfif>>
         #a1#
      </option>
   </cfloop>
</select>
```

Also, not sure if it was omitted deliberately, but .. the two form fields should be nested inside a `<form>` tags.

Comment: This worked, though I tried it with `<cfif id_age1 eq a1>selected</cfif>`. Thank you.

Comment: @gosi123 - Better to scope the variable, ie `form.id_age1` to avoid accidental scope conflicts. It is possible to create the same variable name in multiple scopes. Example `variables.something` and `form.something`. That can lead to unexpected results in some cases. Scoping your variables reduces the likelihood of that happening.

Comment: It is also easier to read because you exactly where the variable came from.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is more of a comment, but it is easier to read as an answer.

The code on the input is not safe. It is subject to HTML Injection. See: [html-injections](/questions/tagged/html-injections)

```
<cfparam name="form.tx_name" default="">
...
<input type="text" name="tx_name" value="#EncodeForHTMLAttribute(tx_name)#" />
```

ColdFusion has a series of functions to address this. See: http://blogs.adobe.com/security/2014/05/coldfusion-11-enhances-the-security-foundation-of-coldfusion-10.html